# Pandas groupby does not set index correctly

Tags: python, pandas, group

i'm a bit confused by the behaviour of the pandas groupby function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"row_id":[1,2,3], "group": [1,2,2], "col1":[1,100,2], "col2":[2,200,2]})

for i, e in df.groupby("group", as_index=True):
  print(e.index)
```

Here I would expect that I will get the "group" column as a new index. However the print returns:

```
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Thus having kept the "old" index. Also the column "group" is still in place as seperate column.

Shouldnt be the result like:

```
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([2, 2], dtype='int64')
```

I dont understand the logic, esp. as as_index=False doesn't change anything.

P.s. I am using pandas 1.3.5

Comment: You're iterating over chunks of the **original** dataframe that belong to different groups. That's all [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__.html) will yield.

Answer (score 2):

`as_index` changes the output format only:

> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index. Only relevant for DataFrame input. as_index=False is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output.

```
>>> df.groupby('group', as_index=False).first()
   group  row_id  col1  col2
0      1       1     1     2
1      2       2   100   200

>>> df.groupby('group', as_index=True).first()
       row_id  col1  col2
group                    
1           1     1     2
2           2   100   200
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. The problem seems to be that i loose the index if i apply a function on my groupby object. What would be the best solution to keep the index in the return of my apply function?

Comment: As you use `groupby`, the output result is aggregated so keep the index does not mean much except if you use `transform` to broadcast the result. Can you provide a sample and the expected output, please?